# using clang to generate call graph for a project

Tags: c++, clang, autoconf, call-graph

I have c and c++ project, and i would like to check for dead function (function that could not be called), for that i want to build a call graph and see which could not be accessed from the written code.
for that i want to use clang with the flag "-S -emit-llvm" so i could creat a dot file.
im using autoconf to compile the project and the autoconfig dont recognize the file that has been compiled as an executable.
tried using this line :

```
./configure --enable-debug --prefix=/opt/ibutils CC=clang CXX=clang++ CXXFLAGS="-S -emit-llvm"
```

and this

```
./configure --enable-debug --prefix=/opt/ibutils CC=clang CXX=clang++ CXXFLAGS="-S -emit-llvm"
            LD="llvm-link"
```

does anyone know the reason? have a suggestions what could i do?
thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. `-S` implies that no object code/executable should be generated, but instead an assembler/llvm file.

Comment: yup i guess i didnt read the man well enough thanks